# Como ajustar o texto do email ao box?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, layout-responsivo

A imagem foi obtida com o browser redimensionado para as dimensões 390 X 650 aproximadamente. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como fazer o texto "**atendimento@emaillongodemais.com.br**" que esta dentro de um `h4` se adeque ao tamanho do `alert` e deixar a responsividade ok.
Estou usando bootstrap 3.6.
Tentei usar @media  no css  e diminui o texto com `font-size:` para 5tp mas ficou microscópico!!
O que devo fazer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Teste Pagina</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.6/css/estilo.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.6/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Projeto</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Produtos.html">Produtos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Servicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="QuemSomos.html">Quem somos</a></li>       
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Contato<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="espaco">
        </div>  

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-3">      
                        <img src="img/phone.png" alt="" title=""  class="img-responsive"/>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">      
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <strong><h3>Televendas:</h3></strong>
                            <h4>
                                (xx) xxxx-xxxx
                                (xx) xxxx-xxxx

                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-3">     
                        <img src="img/arroba.png" alt="" title="" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">      

                        <div class="alert alert-success textoEmail">
                            <strong><h3>Email</h3></strong>.<h4>
                                atendimento@emaillongodemais.com.br</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-offset-1"></div>
                </div>


    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted centralizar">Dinossauro Software.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Aplica um `font-size: Valorempx;` pra regular o tamanho da fonte ou coloca a div como `overflow: hidden;` se não me engano isso faz com que a linha seja quebrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
.textoEmail {overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Fonte [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

Comment: Obrigado , sempre quiz saber como fazer isso!!